# Add event listener on dynamic elements in PolymerJs

Tags: javascript, polymer-1.0

I have an object that dynamically is added to the page. If I add on-tap in the data, when data is added on-tap dosen't work.

```
faqLearning: {
  type: Object,
     value: [ {
     title: 'title',
     text: '<p>hello this is a <a href="#" on-tap="goToOnTap">sample tap</a>.</p>',
        isOpen: false
    }]
}
```

How can I add event listener on dynamic data?

plnkr:
http://plnkr.co/edit/R7VVHn?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like `template-yield` or `juicy-html` to bind HTML or templates to a model.

I was looking for simpler solution and solved the problem by event deligation:

http://plnkr.co/edit/bKkI93?p=preview